# How to change the port number for any service?

Tags: port

I know how to change the port number through the config file of sshd but I want to know how do you change any port number for any service without going into the sshd condfig file or for any service in any case. Thanks.

Comment: This is an overly broad question. There are neither magical formulas nor shortcuts.

Comment: I was going to recommend using an ssh tunnel but it seems like you're trying to change the ssh port itself?

Comment: @Jesse_b Have you read it? A general guide/magical formula to change any port in any existent service in Unix. ssh is just an example.

Answer (score 3):

In short, you can't.  A service will run on the port decreed in its configuration file or, if absent, generally a default.

This *can* be worked around with firewall shenanigans (e. g. listening for an incoming request on TCP/8080 and redirecting it to TCP/80), but that does not change the port the actual service itself is listening on.